# Kotlin, можно ли с помощью html парсера ввести данные в сайт?

Tags: java, html, парсер, kotlin

Мне нужно ввести на сайт логин и пароль, чтобы зайти в аккаунт. Можно ли это сделать на kotlin или java и как? Я не хочу писать код, а потом обломаться из-за того, что данные нельзя ввести через парсер.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсером - нельзя. Потому, что парсер просто получает на вход строку (не сайт, HTML etc, а просто строку) и пытается к этой строке применить код, который вычленит из строки структурированную информацию. За авторизацию парсер не отвечает, т.к. это не область применения оного.

Вы неправильно формулируете свою задачу. Скорее всего она должна звучать так:

> Как программно получить информацию с сайта, который информацию показывает только для авторизованного юзера?

В такой формулировке уже можно дать ответ (обратите внимание, что парсер тут вообще не при чём, важна лишь часть про авторизацию запроса):

1. Изучите как происходит авторизация. В инструментах разработчика браузера найдите какой запрос и как и куда отправляется при логине. Что сервер возвращает на такой запрос. Обычно это будет POST запрос с передачей логина-пароля и получение токена/cookie в ответе в теле/заголовке.
2. Повторите то, что происходит в п1 программно. Вы получите токен/cookie для п3.
3. Теперь изучите аналогично с п1 какой запрос куда и как отправляется при запросе инфы, которая показывается только авторизованному юзеру. Скорее всего к запросу крепится токен/cookie из п2.
4. Повторите то, что происходит в п3 программно. Вы получите информацию, доступную авторизованному юзеру.